# Java DOM XML childnode

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm getting confused and frustrated after a few hours of trying all kinds of things (maybe the stress of it is clouding my abilities here).  My XM string looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><myStuff>
  <paul atrA="46" atrB="10457152"><TEST>hellothere</TEST>
  </paul>
</myStuff>
```

I can extract everything apart from the information contained within TEST.  I need to get the information contained inside TEST.  How do I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
private Map<String, String> parseResponse(final String responseXml) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    System.out.println(responseXml);

    Document doc = parseXml(responseXml);
    return extractAttributes(doc);
}

private Map<String, String> extractAttributes(Document doc) {
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("paul");
    Map<String, String> keyValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            NamedNodeMap attrs = eElement.getAttributes();
            int len = attrs.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                Attr attr = (Attr) attrs.item(i);
                keyValues.put(attr.getNodeName(), attr.getNodeValue());
            }

        }
    }

    return keyValues;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried eElement.getNodeValue() ? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<TEST>` node is a child node of `<paul>` , so you have to do getChildNodes() and then iterate through them.

```
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        // iterate through children here.
        NodeList childrenList = eElement.getChildNodes();
        for ( Node aNode : childrenList ) {
               // YOU SHOULD HAVE TEST HERE
        }
        NamedNodeMap attrs = eElement.getAttributes();
        int len = attrs.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Attr attr = (Attr) attrs.item(i);
            keyValues.put(attr.getNodeName(), attr.getNodeValue());
        }

    }
}
```